# How to implement a replay attack using AODV protocol in omnet++?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I need a snippet of c++ code that simulate AODV network with a malicious node that does a replay attack. I need to embed this in my OMNet++ project.

I tried to change the original code in the sample project in OMNet++ but I'm back at the starting point.

It'll be great to find help.

I can't include a sample code it's fairly long in characters, if you need to see my trials until now, show me where can I share my project.

Comment: i doubt "there is a specific class you could make changes or a specific set of commands" to achieve the behavior you want... your best bet would be to create a new application (new class) that will reflect the behavior that you want... if you modify your question and explain your algorithm in detail and what your application is supposed to do then we could provide some help... you can add some specific types in the messages your application exchange so certain nodes react only to certain messages...

Comment: what does `AODVRouting::handleMessage(msg);` do?

Comment: It basically finds out the type of the received packet, and reroutes again using AODV to the destination.

Comment: add it to the question if you are seeking help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OPs question lacks some details, I will provide a mock solution following [Wikipedia article's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) for the *Replay attack*:

> Suppose Alice wants to prove her identity to Bob. Bob requests her
>   password as proof of identity, which Alice dutifully provides
>   (possibly after some transformation like a hash function); meanwhile,
>   Eve is eavesdropping on the conversation and keeps the password (or
>   the hash). After the interchange is over, Eve (posing as Alice)
>   connects to Bob; when asked for a proof of identity, Eve sends Alice's
>   password (or hash) read from the last session, which Bob accepts thus
>   granting access to Eve.

---

I would create a new packet (extending the UDPPacket) to serve your specific application goal, by adding **source** and **destination** fields to the UDPPacket:

```
cplusplus {{                
#include "<directory_path_for_the_udp_packet_goes_here>/UDPPacket_m.h"      // inheriting the parent class

}}

class ExtendedUDPPacket;    // you can call it whatever you want

message ExtendedUDPPacket extends UDPPacket 
{
    string sourceNode;          // name of the sender
    string destinationNode;         // name of the receiver
}
```

---

Now let's look at the 3 different roles in the given example:

1. Alice: needs to authenticate
2. Bob: authenticator
3. Eve: eavesdropper

If we consider that each node has a specific ID which holds its name we can do the following for each role:

ALICE:

```
void MalAODVRouter::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    ExtendedUDPPacket *eUDPmsg = dynamic_cast<UDPPacket *>(msg);
    if (this->myID == eUDPmsg->getDestinationNode())      // myID is "Alice"
    {
        ExtendedUDPPacket *ExtendedUDPPacket= new UDPPacket();
        ExtendedUDPPacket->setSourceAddress(myID.c_str());
        ExtendedUDPPacket->setDestinationAddress(std::string("Bob").c_str());

        send(udpPacket, "ipOut");
    }
}
```

EVE:

```
void MalAODVRouter::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    ExtendedUDPPacket *eUDPmsg = dynamic_cast<UDPPacket *>(msg);
    if (this->myID != eUDPmsg->getDestinationNode())      // myID is "Eve"
    {
        ExtendedUDPPacket *ExtendedUDPPacket= new UDPPacket();
        ExtendedUDPPacket->setSourceAddress(std::string("Alice").c_str());  // fake the message
        ExtendedUDPPacket->setDestinationAddress(std::string("Bob").c_str());

        send(udpPacket, "ipOut");
    }
}
```

BOB:

```
void MalAODVRouter::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    ExtendedUDPPacket *eUDPmsg = dynamic_cast<UDPPacket *>(msg);
    if (eUDPmsg->getSourceNode() == 'Alice')   
    {
        ExtendedUDPPacket *ExtendedUDPPacket= new UDPPacket();
        ExtendedUDPPacket->setSourceAddress(std::string("Bob").c_str());
        ExtendedUDPPacket->setDestinationAddress(std::string("Alice").c_str());


        send(udpPacket, "ipOut");
    }
}
```

---

Bear in mind this is a mock implementation, you can add smarter conditional checks to make the application behave better.